# Unable to add <ScrollView> to an android app widget layout

Tags: android

I am trying to create a widget to an application, following is the layout I'm using. I've tried to add the scroll view to the second half part of the widget. I am unable to do that, When I removed  tags, widget is getting displayed, but when with  tags, android is unable to load the widget. I am scratching my head with this for two days. I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    >

        <RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:id="@+id/widgetHeader"
            >

            <Button 
              android:background="@drawable/icon_quickword"
              android:id="@+id/widgetBtn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_margin="5sp" 
             />

            <TextView android:text="@string/widget_title1"
              android:id="@+id/widget_title1" 
              android:textSize="18sp"   
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/widgetBtn"
              android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
              />

            <TextView android:text="@string/widget_title2"
              android:id="@+id/widget_title2" 
              android:textSize="15sp"   
              android:textStyle="italic"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/widgetBtn"
              android:layout_below="@id/widget_title1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
              />


        </RelativeLayout>   

            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/widgetContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                >

                <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info1"
                  android:id="@+id/widget_content_info1"
                  android:textStyle="bold" 
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info2"
                  android:id="@+id/widget_content_info2"
                  android:textSize="14sp" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black" />   

                <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info3"
                  android:id="@+id/widget_content_info3"
                  android:textSize="14sp" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textColor="@android:color/black" />   

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use a ListView instead

Answer (score 5):

Scrollview is Only Supported Above Similar kind OF widgets which Are More Than One

Comment: The Scrolling sideways(HorizontalScrollView) is not supported. The ScrollView, I believe is supported.

Comment: I tried with scroll view in appwidget, but the widget is not even loading. And the official documentation doesn't list Scroll view as supported

Answer (score 5):

you can use ListView with only 1 list item (your layout)

get sample for list view [here](https://codeload.github.com/laaptu/appwidget-listview/zip/appwidget-listview1)

and modified ListProvider.java

```
public int getCount() {
return 1;
}
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_origin_layout);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, "your Text");
    // add other pocess here
    return remoteView;
}
```

Comment: It's really helpfull!

Answer (score 2):

```
        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widgetContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

        <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info1"
          android:id="@+id/widget_content_info1"
          android:textStyle="bold" 
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info2"
          android:id="@+id/widget_content_info2"
          android:textSize="14sp" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black" />   

        <TextView android:text="@string/widget_content_info3"
          android:id="@+id/widget_content_info3"
          android:textSize="14sp" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black" />   

    </LinearLayout>

    **</ScrollView>**
```

Comment: ur not end scroll view tag

Comment: I should not be using </ScrollView> tag, but why? what If I just want to give scrollable view in the middle of the screen, keeping above and below parts fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll view  can only host one child, better use a ListView

Answer (score 0):

After using all attributes close your view with end tag. close your `ScrollView` With end tag.

```
<ScrollView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widgetContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I've added </ScrollView>, still something's wrong, updated question with new layout.

Comment: Add some more text try it. because its length to short.